# How can I rewrite null checks with optional in a better way

Tags: java, option-type

I am having a small snippet of code. I would like to write it in a better way with fewer nested checks. How can I achieve it?

```
Item item = itemResponse.getItem();
Optional<Item> optionalItem = Optional.ofNullable(item);
if (optionalItem.isPresent()) {
    List<NameValue> listValues = item.getValues();
    Optional<List<NameValue>> optionalListValues = Optional.ofNullable(listValues);
    if (optionalListValues.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println(listValues);
    }
}
```

Is there any concise way I can rewrite the above piece of code using Java 8?

Comment: **Do not** rewrite null checks with optional. It is not better, rather worse.

Comment: And Optional purpose is different, it's not for null check.

Comment: This use of `Optional` is suspect.  Most uses of `Optional` should be as return types from methods.  This use signals to clients of the method that the method may not be able to return a value and that the client will need to handle this possibility.  Other uses of `Optional` are likely to be a bad smell in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `itemResponse.getItem()` class to return `Optional<Item>` and use the chained [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method which will executed only if `Optional` has value, and if `map` method return non null value then only final `ifPresent(Consumer consumer)` is executed

```
Optional<Item> item = itemResponse.getItem()

item.map(item::getValues)
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: OP is simply using `isPresent` for `!=null`, which is better achievable without `map` IMHO.

Comment: I think if he use `map` method he don't need to check `ifPresent` again, as per my research the last `ifPresent(System.out::println)` is executing if `map` returns non null value @Naman

Comment: with the code shared, it currently looks as if OP is willing to print the `item.getValues()` only if both `item` and `item.getValues()` are non-null(mostly to avoid NPE). So the code `if(item !=null && item.getValues() !=null) {  System.out.println(item.getValues());`}` should just be it.

Comment: yeah that correct, but if he is using the chained methods like `map` he don't need to have null check at all right ? looks like OP is searching for how to avoid null checks using `Optional` @Naman, But i don't know the OP thought process